# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, migration, cdi, upgrade, wildfly

I've reviewed the other related questions on SO, and haven't found the answer to my question.

I am upgrading from JBoss AS 7.11 to Wildfly 8.2 and have encountered what people are calling the "infamous `WELD-001408`" issue.  However, my situation seems to be different in that we are not using any `@Inject` annotations, or anything that should cause a validation error as far as I know.

The stack trace below seems to indicate that the exception is caused by the weld Validator itself with the qualifier `@Default`.  Does this make any sense to anyone?

I emphasize that there are neither `@Inject` nor `@Default` annotations in my application anywhere.  So, the exception is mysterious.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get my application up and running in Wildfly 8.2?

If any additional information is needed, please ask and I will supply it, if possible.

Thanks!!!

edit [12-May-2015]:

I wonder if it has something to do with the hibernate validator?

From the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Am I using the hibernate validator correctly?  Is there some configuration that needs to be supplied?  Is there another validator that can be used instead?

---

Stack trace from startup of wildfly:

```
11:21:57,196 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."search.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."search.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]

Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: 

** Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private **
org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator
  at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator(ValidationInterceptor.java:0)
WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
  - ValidatorBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorBean_hv]

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:372)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:293)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInterceptor(Validator.java:569)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$2.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:85)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$2.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:83)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: Do you happen to have any `javax.validation` annotations on your rest endpoints?

Comment: @JohnAment - No, there are no validation annotations on the rest endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Try marking hibernate validator as provided.

Comment: I changed the scope of the hibernate validator to provided and got the error: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.

Comment: Hmmm how are you getting a reference to validator? manually building it or injecting it as a resource somewhere?

Comment: @JohnAment I haven't done anything to instantiate or inject a validator.  I assume it is something that weld is doing on its own.  I'm coming straight from the world of JBoss 7 and am just coming up to speed on these changes, and I haven't made any changes in the code or configuration to accommodate the validation, with the single exception of adding the pom dependency for the hibernate validator.

Comment: FYI - check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki). It doesn't have any rules for your use case, but may have in the future. Especially if you decide to contribute :)

Answer (score 2):

**Sorry (I know you are using JBoss or Wildfly)**, but i just adding this answer for who are using Liberty or Websphere servers because same message "`WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default`" appears in these servers too.

Anyway may the problem description help you to solve your problem in JBoss

**Problem description**

> If your application includes the class Validator.class
>   (including in internal jar files) Liberty may get confused
>   between the the classfile in your application and the class
>   file installed inside liberty itself leading to a
>   WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator
>   with qualifiers @Default exception.

I had your problem but in **Liberty V16.0.0.3** and i fixed it by adding

`<cdi12 enableImplicitBeanArchives="false"/>`

in **server.xml** file

And here are the link which describe the problem and fixing of it
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI71667

BTW this is already fixed in **Liberty V16.0.0.4 (Last version now)**

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem on Wildfly 9 after migration from JBoss EAP 6.2! And workaround form 
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2708 helped to me.
So in your active `standalone.xml` file for *weld* subsystem configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:2.0"/>
```

add attribute **require-bean-descriptor="true"**, it will look like:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:2.0" require-bean-descriptor="true"/>
```